# D3js Is it possible create view like tree structure with custom nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have requirement to list different activities with three states of each one with different colors as a status.Each activity will have many activities and each should draggable to replace it's position. Below image give you clear idea [image]

Is it possible with [d3.js](http://d3js.org/)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's absolutely possible. Are there any more details you need??

Comment: yes  [using this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083) ,but i cannot customize the nodes to make it squares with different colors . Do have any idea that how to customize node ?? @keoghpe

Comment: You need to change this line:  `nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });` If you have some attribute in the data you can use that to change the colour returned from the function. You can append a [rectangle instead of a circle](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-basic-shapes-and-d3js)